# Get form/fieldset element name inside custom validator class in ZF3

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework3

I created my custom validator class that implemented ValidatorInterface. How to get element name of the fieldset or form that is validated?

I need this inside the validator class.

I am going to do some validating logic inside the class validator cause I am going to use the context array with all values and distinguish which is the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you can't. But you can use callable filter to re-design your value. I don't know if it's reasonable way to do it. I didn't face such a problem like this. But here's an example

```
$this->add([
   /** other settings **/
   "filters" => [
       [
          "name" => \Zend\Filter\Callable::class,
          "options" => ["callback" => function($value){
                return "fieldset-x:".$value;
          }]
       ]
   ],
   "validators" => [
      [
         "name" => \Zend\Validator\Callable::class,
         "options" => ["callback" => function($value){
              /** algorithm: split via ":". first element is freamwork **/
         }]
      ]
   ]
])
```

I used `callable` filter and validator to do is. You may want to write your own filter/validator.

Comment: I understand your idea. That is clever. My goal is not to create an individual validator class for several form elements. Another idea would be to create a fat abstract validator class and let inherit it special validator classes that would be unique for each form element.

Comment: Don't event think about fat abstract validator. It'll be shit hole, i guarantee it. I think you should write separate validators. I don't know.. I suffered like this "lazy" actions a lot. I'm doing everything as like as have to be now a days :)